# Video and audio blending/fading with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to evaluate functionality in gstreamer for applicability in a new application.

The application should be able to dynamically play videos and images depending on a few criteria (user input, ...) not really relevant for this question. The main thing I was not able to figure out was how I can achieve seamless crossfading/blending between successive content.

I was thinking about using the videomixer plugin and programatically transition the sinks alpha values. However, I'm not sure if this would work nor if it is a good idea to do so.

A gstreamer solution would be prefered because of the availability on development and target platform. Furthermore, a custom videosink implementation may be used in the end for rendering the content to proprietary displays.

**Edit:** Was able to code up a prototype using two file-sources fed into a videomixer, using GstInterpolationControlSource and GstTimedValueControlSource to bind and interpolate the videomixer alpha control inputs. The fades look perfect, however, what I did not quite have on the radar was that I cannot dynamically change the file sources location while the pipeline is running. Furthermore, it feels like misusing functions not intended for the job at hand.

Any feedback on how to tackle this use case would still be very much appreachiated. Thanks!

Comment: Check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-editing-services/?gi-language=c

Comment: Thanks, I was already contemplating that library but was a bit scared away because the documentation always talks about "editing-related applications". I think I don't get the whole picture yet and how such a library can fit in.

I'm not that familiar with gstreamer, basically we only use it for creating dynamic pipelines with custom sources and sinks.

Comment: I understand that I can build up a GESTimeline with all the media that should be played including crossfades between them. However, I'm not quite sure how to deal with fading out the currently playing media while fading in a different one which was requested by the user. Furthermore, how I would repeat a group of media in an endless loop when no user input occurs, again with fades inbetween also from last to first in queue.